# "rec FAIL formats: no handler for file extension 'json'" error using bash scripting with asciinema rec command

Tags: json, bash, shell, scripting, record

I'm trying to concatenate all of the inputs for executing different shell session recorders.  This code block keeps throwing the error `rec FAIL formats: no handler for file extension 'json'`, which is confusing to me because the asciinema rec command outputs .json files.

```
case $program_choice in
1)
    PROGRAM=asciinema
    DUMP_PATH="${DUMP_PATH}${PROGRAM}_dump/"
    COMMAND="rec"
    ARGUMENTS="-q"
    # -q is quiet
    EXTENSION=".json"
    LOG_FILE=${DUMP_PATH}${PROGRAM}_$(date +"%Y-%b-%d-%H:%M:%S")${EXTENSION}
    EXECUTE=$PROGRAM $COMMAND $ARGUMENTS $LOG_FILE
    ;;
esac
```

Here's a link to the asciinema commands documentation: https://asciinema.org/docs/usage

and more background info about asciinema in general: https://asciinema.org/docs/how-it-works

Comment: What's the actual full command that gives this error?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out; I just needed double quotes around the right side of the assignment for EXECUTE.

ie:

```
EXECUTE="$PROGRAM $COMMAND $ARGUMENTS $LOG_FILE"
```